# bootstrapping by multiple groups in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, broom

I'm trying to bootstrap a bivariate correlation grouped by multiple variables in a tidy fashion. So far I've got:

```
paks <- c('dplyr','tidyr','broom')
lapply(paks, require, character.only=TRUE)
set.seed(123)

df <- data.frame(
  rep(c('group1','group2','group3','group4'),25),
  rep(c('subgroup1','subgroup2','subgroup3','subgroup4'),25),
  rnorm(25),
  rnorm(25)
)
colnames(df) <- c('group','subgroup','v1','v2') 

cors_boot <- df %>%
  group_by(., group,subgroup) %>% 
  bootstrap(., 10) %>% 
  do(tidy(cor.test(.$v1,.$v2)))
cors_boot
```

This will succesffuly run 10 replications, but will not maintain the `group_by` conditions. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option is to make use of nested tibbles (using `nest()` from tidyr) and iterating with functions from the purrr package. Here's an example:

```
df %>% 
  nest(-group, -subgroup) %>% 
  mutate(cors_boot = map(data, ~ bootstrap(., 10) %>% do(tidy(cor.test(.$v1,.$v2))))) %>% 
  unnest(cors_boot)
#> # A tibble: 40 × 11
#>     group  subgroup replicate   estimate statistic    p.value parameter
#>    <fctr>    <fctr>     <int>      <dbl>     <dbl>      <dbl>     <int>
#> 1  group1 subgroup1         1 0.30199080 1.5192285 0.14233305        23
#> 2  group1 subgroup1         2 0.24782068 1.2267744 0.23231801        23
#> 3  group1 subgroup1         3 0.05697887 0.2737057 0.78675375        23
#> 4  group1 subgroup1         4 0.14141925 0.6851084 0.50012255        23
#> 5  group1 subgroup1         5 0.14769543 0.7161768 0.48109119        23
#> 6  group1 subgroup1         6 0.23407050 1.1546390 0.26009439        23
#> 7  group1 subgroup1         7 0.09388988 0.4522780 0.65530564        23
#> 8  group1 subgroup1         8 0.38602977 2.0068956 0.05665478        23
#> 9  group1 subgroup1         9 0.20248790 0.9916399 0.33169177        23
#> 10 group1 subgroup1        10 0.27430083 1.3679706 0.18453909        23
#> # ... with 30 more rows, and 4 more variables: conf.low <dbl>,
#> #   conf.high <dbl>, method <fctr>, alternative <fctr>
```

Note that data setup is all the same except the purrr package is also loaded:

```
paks <- c('dplyr','tidyr','broom','purrr')
lapply(paks, require, character.only=TRUE)
set.seed(123)

df <- data.frame(
  rep(c('group1','group2','group3','group4'),25),
  rep(c('subgroup1','subgroup2','subgroup3','subgroup4'),25),
  rnorm(25),
  rnorm(25)
)
colnames(df) <- c('group','subgroup','v1','v2')
```

Aside, if they're new to you, I've written a little about nested tibbles in some blog posts. E.g., [here](https://drsimonj.svbtle.com/running-a-model-on-separate-groups).

Answer (score 4):

It appears that after the `bootstrap` function, it is grouped by bootstrap `replicates` instead of `group` and `subgroup`

```
df %>%
    group_by(group,subgroup) %>% 
    bootstrap(10, by_group=TRUE)
# Source: local data frame [100 x 4]
# Groups: replicate [10]
```

hence, you will need to regroup again after `bootstrap` (pls note that your `v1` and `v2` in `df` is recycled so the values returned from `cor.test` are the same for each combination of `group` and `subgroup`. i changed `v1` and `v2` in the example below as a sanity check)

```
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(
    group=rep(c('group1','group2','group3','group4'), 25),
    subgroup=rep(c('subgroup1','subgroup2','subgroup3','subgroup4'), 25),
    v1=rnorm(100),
    v2=rnorm(100)
)

cors_boot <- df %>%
    group_by(group,subgroup) %>% 
    bootstrap(10, by_group=TRUE) %>% 
    group_by(group, subgroup) %>% #add in this line to make your code work
    do(tidy(cor.test(.$v1,.$v2)))
cors_boot
```

Comment: I have a similar problem as the poster. When I try your solution, it does re-group, however, It seems as though the replicated datasets are lost.