# Bootstrapping by multiple groups in the tidyverse: rsample vs. broom

Tags: r, tidyverse, resampling

In [this SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42986736/bootstrapping-by-multiple-groups-in-dplyr) bootstrapping by several groups and subgroups seemed to be easy using the `broom::bootstrap` function specifying the `by_group` argument with `TRUE`.

My desired output is a nested tibble with n rows where the data column contains the bootstrapped data generated by each bootstrap call (and each group and subgroup has the same amount of cases as in the original data).

In `broom` I did the following:

```
# packages
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(tidyr)
library(tibble)
library(rsample)
library(broom)

# some data to bootstrap
set.seed(123)
data <- tibble(
  group=rep(c('group1','group2','group3','group4'), 25),
  subgroup=rep(c('subgroup1','subgroup2','subgroup3','subgroup4'), 25),
  v1=rnorm(100),
  v2=rnorm(100)
)

# the actual approach using broom::bootstrap
tibble(id = 1:100) %>% 
  mutate(data = map(id, ~ {data %>%
      group_by(group,subgroup) %>% 
      broom::bootstrap(100, by_group=TRUE)}))
```

Since the `broom::bootstrap` function is deprecated, I rebuild my approach with the desired output using `rsample::bootstraps`. It seems to be much more complicated to get my desired output. Am I doing something wrong or have things gotten more complicated in the tidyverse when generating grouped bootstraps?

```
data %>%
  dplyr::mutate(group2 = group,
                subgroup2 = subgroup) %>% 
  tidyr::nest(-group2, -subgroup2) %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(boot  = map(data, ~ rsample::bootstraps(., 100))) %>% 
  pull(boot) %>% 
  purrr::map(., "splits") %>% 
  transpose %>% 
  purrr::map(., ~ purrr::map_dfr(., rsample::analysis)) %>% 
  tibble(id = 1:length(.), data = .)
```

Answer (score 1):

Annoyingly, the `strata` argument to `rsample::bootstraps()` only accepts a single variable, but we can use `tidyr::unite()` to solve this.

I'm hoping this gets you what you want.

```r
data %>%
  unite("final_group", group, subgroup, remove = FALSE) %>%
  rsample::bootstraps(100, strata = final_group) %>%
  transmute(
    id = 1:100,
    data = map(splits, rsample::analysis)
  )
```

Comment: Sorry for getting back to you answer late, I was travelling. The idea with `unite` and the `strata` argument is great. However, in your current approach, every bootstrap interation contains the same data. If you assign the result to `res` then try `res$data[[1]]` and `res$data[[2]]`. Its the same data. In my approach each iteration is unique.